# Can you create a resizable control in SWT?

Tags: eclipse, swt

I am currently working with the SWT package in Eclipse. Is it possible to create a resizable control within a composite control.

For instance, if I have a tree control which I would like to expand, but in order to view the sub tree items I would like to 'click and drag' the border of the tree to resize it, much like the draggable divider in the [Eclipse help website](http://help.eclipse.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the SWT [Sash](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#sash) is what you are looking for.

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DemonstratesaSash.htm) is a good example on how to use it.

**EDIT**:

Just found that [SashForm](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/SashForm.html) is much easier to use. See [LINK](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SashFormExample.htm) for a good example.

Comment: That is good, but Sash only allows resizing in one direction (either horizontally or vertically). I wonder if there is a way to make it resizable in either direction, like text boxes in browsers.